# Xamarin forms How to pick a Image from Gallery

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I created a simple app I need to select an image in internal Gallery in order to upload it. I tried it with XAm.plugin.media nuget But it does not work it gives error Storage pErmission. In Android Manifest, There is no field to set the access to internal storage it only has external storage How to access internal Image in Xamarin forms

Comment: please read the docs - there are extensive instructions about additional setup steps required for Android.

Comment: @Jason which doc are preferring

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Answer (score 0):

In the Android project, open the AssemblyInfo.cs file under the Properties folder and add:

```
// Needed for Picking photo/video
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)]

// Needed for Taking photo/video
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera)]

// Add these properties if you would like to filter out devices that do not have cameras, or set to false to make them optional
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = true)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = true)]
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android